# Bundle install not finding gem in gem list

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2, bundle-install

I am trying to add devise to my application and gem install works, but everytime I run bundle install, it does not find devise in my gemlist. I have tried including the git link and using a specific version, but it still does not find it in my gemfile.

**Terminal**
$bundle install
`$Using rake (0.9.2.2) 
Using i18n (0.6.0) 
Using multi_json (1.3.6) 
Using activesupport (3.2.5) 
Using builder (3.0.0) 
Using activemodel (3.2.5) 
Using erubis (2.7.0) 
Using journey (1.0.3) 
Using rack (1.4.1) 
Using rack-cache (1.2) 
Using rack-test (0.6.1) 
Using hike (1.2.1) 
Using tilt (1.3.3) 
Using sprockets (2.1.3) 
Using actionpack (3.2.5) 
Using mime-types (1.18) 
Using polyglot (0.3.3) 
Using treetop (1.4.10) 
Using mail (2.4.4) 
Using actionmailer (3.2.5) 
Using arel (3.0.2) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.33) 
Using activerecord (3.2.5) 
Using activeresource (3.2.5) 
Using coffee-script-source (1.3.3) 
Using execjs (1.4.0) 
Using coffee-script (2.2.0) 
Using rack-ssl (1.3.2) 
Using json (1.7.3) 
Using rdoc (3.12) 
Using thor (0.15.2) 
Using railties (3.2.5) 
Using coffee-rails (3.2.2) 
Using jquery-rails (2.0.2) 
Using bundler (1.1.4) 
Using rails (3.2.5) 
Using sass (3.1.19) 
Using sass-rails (3.2.5) 
Using sqlite3 (1.3.6) 
Using uglifier (1.2.4) 
Your bundle is complete! Use`bundle show [gemname]`to see where a bundled gem is installed.`

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.5'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'

gem 'devise'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'


# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
```

Comment: Try running with --verbose
Also check if you have hidden .bundle directory.
I suspect it has to be something with config. Did you try to quickly make new application and require devise there?

Comment: I ran verbose and I checked the gem folders and devise 2.1.0 is located there. I just tried to make a new app but devise wasn't there. How do you require devise?

Comment: Weird. Try running ``gem install devise`` does it work? Also ``rails generate devise:install`` what result do you get?

Comment: gem install devise results in installing the gem, but rails generate devise:install comes back with could not find generator devise:install

Comment: Somehow it was fixed after I tried to add a new gem to the list. Thanks for the help!